# Should I build a function Event emitter?

Tags: web3js, event-handling

Doing some frontend work, I'm sending a transaction using the method:

```
await window.ethereum.request({
      method: 'eth_sendTransaction',
      params: [tx],
})`
```

This is returning me the transaction hash, and I can poll the transaction data returned from it by using `await web3.eth.getTransaction(txHash)` and checking if the `blockNumber` is not null every x seconds.

This is working fine to get the confirmation of the transaction, but I would like to be more generic and avoid to repeat myself in the code, and building some kind of event emitter on this function, by doing so:

```
transactionHelper(tx).on('confirmation', () => {
     // display some cool stuff when inserted in the blocks
})
```

And wrapping this around all the transaction and confirmation logic.
I've seen some tutorials on how to do it on object, but how to subscribe to an event for a function ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Great, so I ended up making a simple function... Here is it, hope it helps other people

```
import { web3 } from './connectors'
import { Transaction, TransactionConfig } from 'web3-core'

// wrapper for a tx
const transactionHelper = async (tx: TransactionConfig) => {
  await window.ethereum
    .request({
      method: 'eth_sendTransaction',
      params: [tx],
    })
    .then((txHash: string) => {
      return new Promise<void>(async (resolve) => {
        // poll the hash every seconds
        const waitForTxMined = async () => {
          // only resolve if it has been mined
          if (await isTxMined(txHash)) return resolve()
          setTimeout(async () => {
            await waitForTxMined()
          }, 1000)
        }
        await waitForTxMined()
      })
    })
}

// check if block number is valid => transaction included
const isTxMined = async (txHash: string): Promise<boolean> => {
  const tx: Transaction = await web3.eth.getTransaction(txHash)
  return tx.blockNumber !== null
}

export { transactionHelper }
```